# Double 可能形? 話せるようになれるまで

Tags: usage, potential-form, idiomaticity

> 日本人は完璧にきれいに話せるようにならないと、「会話が成り立たない」「恥ずかしい」と感じ、なかなか外国語で話しかけられない人が多いように思います。（英語もしかり）しかし完璧に**話せる**ように**なれる**まで、じゃあどこでそれを練習するんですか？という話。([source](https://momen-koreankpp.com/selfstudy-travel/))

> 要は、「あなたが英語が**話せる**ように**なれる**までの「エネルギーの源泉」が、あなたにあるかどうか？」が重要になってきます。([source](https://togawaakio.com/4035/))

> 英語を話せるようになりたいと思っている人は多いものの、実際に**話せる**ように**なれる**までスキルアップするのは難しいですよね。([source](https://www.fpwoman.co.jp/contents/kakeibo/5985))

These sound strange to me because normally people seem to say 話せるようになるまで, and in all of those contexts above it seems 話せるようになるまで should work better. Are these uses idiomatic? Are there any contexts where double 可能形 like this can/should be used?

Also what about 話すようになれる? Are there contexts where the 可能形 should be with なる as opposed to be with the verb before ように?

> 地道に英語を毎日聞いている成果が、確実に出てますね。今は、ホテル・食事・買い物は、ほとんど困らないレベルかな。ペラペラ話すように**なれる**まで、何年でも学ぶつもり。([source](https://4travel.jp/travelogue/10686700))

I thought in this sentence the phrase may work because 話す is modified by ペラペラ but even in such a sentence doesn't ペラペラ話せるようになる work better?

> なんで毎日サウナで会ってる人も最初は挨拶無し。そのうち頭を下げる。そしてやっと話すように**なれる**まで２年以上が普通です。([source](http://sunboy.blog.jp/archives/52165576.html))

> 父の事を普通に話すように**なれる**までは私には長い時間が必要です。([source](https://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/topics/id/924957/))

These two are tricky. I feel like they work with 話すようになれるまで, but do they not work with 話せるようになるまで too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, I think you are right about 話せるようになれる, and it does sound odd if you think about it. At the same time, it should be the kind of redundancy that passes unnoticed in ordinary usage.

In the first three examples, 話せるようになる is enough and more natural. Also in the other three, 話せるようになる works. But, as you suspected, in the last two, it is more like 'the situation/relationship comes to the state such that...' rather than ability, so 話すようになれる sounds less unnatural.